# pyplot set colors when y is a list of values

Tags: matplotlib, colors

Starting from the original code and plot:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
plt.plot(df[['A2A.MI','IG.MI']])
plt.yscale('log')
plt.legend(('A2A','IG'))
```

I get:
[image]

I'd like to change colors for both lines but...for some reason I don't remember how to handle colors when y values are set as above (list).
Is there a way to do it or I have to write 'plt.plot' twice?
Thanks

Comment: Would you consider pandas or seaborn's plotting? For example with pandas: `df[['x', 'y']].plot(color=['turquoise', 'tomato'])`. With standard matplotlib, the easiest is to just call it twice:  `plt.plot(df['x'], color='turquoise', label='x'); plt.plot(df['y'], color='tomato', label='y'); plt.legend()`.

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake in the first part of df[....].plot().  It works the way you wrote it. Thanks